# how to connect SQL server db with windows authentication from eclipse db perspective

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, eclipse

How to connect SQL server db 2008 with windows authentication from eclipse db perspective.

I don't have permission to put sqlserver .dll file on java library path or system 32 or even to set path to machine.

So I try to do that using some modification on eclipse.ini file. I try to add -Djava.library.path="sql server.dll" on eclipse.ini after -vm line but still it is throwing driver is not configured for Integrated Security.

Answer (score 0):

Put sqljdbc_auth.dll on eclipse setup root folder.